# Fill a FontAwesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to fill the times-circle icon from FontAwesome which is transparent inside.

```
<i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

So I tried to apply a background-color: white to this element but since the element is squared I have a squared background. I also tried to apply a border-radius: 100% to obtain a rounded element but nothing...

So my question is how to fill the cross inside this icon ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked

Stack your icons using the `fa-stack` class and `fa-stack-Nx` classes for your icons:

```css
.fa-stack .fa-circle{
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

More examples:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
fa-twitter on fa-square-o<br>


<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
fa-flag on fa-circle<br>


<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-terminal fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
fa-terminal on fa-square<br>


<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
</span>
fa-ban on fa-camera
```